# Theano function: Unused input

Tags: python, numpy, k-means, theano

I am trying to implement mini-batch Kmeans. The part that seems to be giving me a really hard time is specifying the minibatches as inputs to theano. I have a `KmeansMiniBatch` class with an `__init__(self, batch_size, data=None)` function, where `data` is in this case the minibatch, and `batch_size` is the size of the batch. I also have a `fit_once` function which takes no arguments, but instead uses the data passed to `__init__`.

My main script consists of the following:

```
X = T.matrix('X', dtype='float64')
mini_batch = T.matrix('X', dtype='float64')

kmeans = KmeansMiniBatch(
    batch_size=10000,
    data=X
)

func = theano.function(
    inputs=[mini_batch],
    outputs=kmeans.fit_once(),
    givens={
        kmeans.X: mini_batch,
    }
)

data = load_data()
for i in xrange(30):
    func(get_batch(data))

image = Image.fromarray(
tile_raster_images(X=np.transpose(kmeans.D.eval()),
                       img_shape=(12, 12), tile_shape=(10, 30),
                       tile_spacing=(1, 1)))
```

What I intended to do was to initialize a KmeansMiniBatch object with a symbolic variable `X`, which gets replaced by the a `mini_batch` at each iteration. Each of the minibatches is generated by the function `get_batch` which basically takes as input the entire dataset, and using `numpy.random.choice` returns only a subset of that dataset, which is a `numpy` array. Unfortunately, I cannot seem to accomplish what I set out to achieve, as the above code results in the following error message:

> theano.compile.function_module.UnusedInputError: theano.function was asked to create a function computing outputs given certain inputs, but the provided input variable at index 0 is not part of the computational graph needed to compute the outputs: X.
>   To make this error into a warning, you can pass the parameter on_unused_input='warn' to theano.function. To disable it completely, use on_unused_input='ignore'.

I am not sure why exactly I do get this error, since I do replace the symbolic variable `X` by the function input `mini_batch`. Furthermore, if I do set `on_unused_input='ignore'` I end up with the following error message during evaluating `kmeans.D.eval()`:

> theano.gof.fg.MissingInputError: ("An input of the graph, used to compute Shape(X), was not provided and not given a value.Use the Theano flag exception_verbosity='high',for more information on this error.", X)

Any help would be very much appreciated !

---

Edit:

So I finally got it working ! My `fit_once` function used to update a matrix `D`, which is an attribute of the class KmeanMiniBatch, but didn't return it, which apparently caused `theano` to complain, since the input was indeed not used in the output. What I did is, I modified `fit_once` to return `D`, and that basically solved the issue. Here is my modified `main`

```
X = T.matrix('X', dtype='float64')
mini_batch = T.matrix('mini_batch', dtype='float64')

kmeans = KmeansMiniBatch(
    batch_size=1000,
    data=X
)

func = theano.function(
    inputs=[mini_batch],
    outputs=kmeans.fit_once(),
    givens={
        X: mini_batch
    },
)

data = load_data()
D= None
for i in xrange(30):
    D = func(get_batch(data))

image = Image.fromarray(
tile_raster_images(X=np.transpose(D),
                       img_shape=(12, 12), tile_shape=(10, 30),
                       tile_spacing=(1, 1)))
image.save('repflds7.png')
```

Apparently `theano` functions do not play well with void python functions.

---

Edit 2:

Just to shed some more light on the problem that I would like to solve. So, the version of `Kmeans` I am implementing is also know as `Vector Quantization`, whereby a dictionary `D` basically provides a compression for the dataset `X` into `S`. Initially, the part of `fit_once` concerning `D` was as follows:

```
self.D = T.dot(self.X, T.transpose(S))
self.D = self.D / T.sqrt(T.sum(T.sqr(self.D), axis=0))
```

So basically, at every iteration the dictionary `D` would be updated, and it would therefore, make no sense to return `D`, which I had to do in order to stop `theano` from complaining:

```
self.D = T.dot(self.X, T.transpose(S))
self.D = self.D / T.sqrt(T.sum(T.sqr(self.D), axis=0))
return self.D
```

D is initialized as follows in `__init__`:

```
self.D = self.srng.normal(size=(self.dimensions, self.K))
self.D = self.D / T.sqrt(T.sum(T.sqr(self.D), axis=0))
```

What I would like to achieve is:
1. Not have to return `D`, but instead update, and evaluate `D` in place, which I can then retrieve through `kmeans.D`
2. I am not about my choice of having `D` as a symbolic variable? Perhaps a shared variable would be a better choice?
3. Most importantly, at each of the 30 iterations, I would like to substitute the data `X` to the `KmeansMiniBatch` model with a minibatch, and hence, my use of the givens param. Is there a better way to achieve that?

Comment: There's a lot of weird stuff going on in that code. You have two Theano variables called 'X'. You use `mini_batch` as an input, but then you also shoehorn it into `givens` (I'm pretty sure you're misusing `givens`). You say `fit_once` updates `D`, but your `theano.function` call has no `updates` parameter. You didn't show us the code for `fit_once`, but what did it return before? If it didn't return anything before, then it makes no sense to specify it as the `outputs`. And so on.

Comment: @cfh I updated my answer with details. I am pretty sure that in my code I do, in some sense, abuse `theano`, which is why I hope to improve it. Should you need any more details, please let me know. I also edited the duplicate variables mistake.

Comment: You may have some basic misgivings about how Theano works. `fit_once` has to return something because it will only be executed once, namely when you construct the `function` object, and what it returns is supposed to be a symbolic computation graph which tells Theano what to compute whenever `func` is invoked. If `fit_once` doesn't return anything, your function has `outputs=None`, and that means that `func` won't actually compute anything (since it also doesn't have an `updates=` clause). Maybe revisit some tutorials to see how this all fits together.

Answer (score 3):

As far as you as a user of Theano are concerned, symbolic variables do not support a concept of "current value" or "updating". For that you would need a shared variable.

You need to be clearer on how you would like to use your `KmeansMiniBatch` class. At the moment it does not encapsulate the D-updating behaviour since the Theano function is compiled and executed outside of `KmeansMiniBatch`. You might prefer a usage like this:

```
kmeans = KmeansMiniBatch()

data = load_data()
for i in xrange(30):
    kmeans.update(get_batch(data, batch_size=10000))

image = Image.fromarray(
tile_raster_images(X=np.transpose(kmeans.get_D()),
                       img_shape=(12, 12), tile_shape=(10, 30),
                       tile_spacing=(1, 1)))
```

Note that there is no Theano functionality visible here, that's all encapsulated into the `KmeansMiniBatch` class. We also don't need to tell `KmeansMiniBatch` what the batch size is because that doesn't change the symbolic expression; instead we tell `get_batch` how large a batch to get.

Inside `KmeansMiniBatch` you have two possible approaches.

1. Make `D` a shared variable and use `updates=...` in your Theano function to change its contents on each `update`.

   ```
   class KmeansMiniBatch:
       def __init__(dimensions, K):
           # ... init srng ...
           D = srng.normal(size=(dimensions, K))
           D = D / numpy.sqrt(numpy.sum(numpy.sqr(D), axis=0)))
           self.D = theano.shared(D, 'D')
           mini_batch = T.matrix('mini_batch', dtype='float64')
           self.func = theano.function(inputs=[mini_batch], updates=fit_once(mini_batch))

       def update(batch):
           self.func(batch)

       def fit_once(mini_batch):
           # ... do work to create S symbolically ...
           D_update = T.dot(mini_batch, T.transpose(S))
           D_update = D_update / T.sqrt(T.sum(T.sqr(D_update), axis=0))
           return [(self.D, D_update)]

       def get_D():
           return self.D.get_value()
   ```

   Note that the init of D has changed from a Theano operation to a numpy operation.
2. Make `D` a regular numpy array, pass it in as an input to your Theano function, and change the value to the output of your Theano function, on each `update`.

   ```
   class KmeansMiniBatch:
       def __init__(dimensions, K):
           # ... init srng ...
           self.D = srng.normal(size=(dimensions, K))
           self.D = self.D / numpy.sqrt(numpy.sum(numpy.sqr(self.D), axis=0)))
           mini_batch = T.matrix('mini_batch', dtype='float64')
           self.func = theano.function(inputs=[mini_batch], outputs=fit_once())

       def update(batch):
           self.D = self.func(batch)

       def fit_once(mini_batch):
           # ... do work to create S symbolically ...
           D_update = T.dot(mini_batch, T.transpose(S))
           D_update = D_update / T.sqrt(T.sum(T.sqr(D_update), axis=0))
           return D_update

       def get_D():
           return self.D
   ```

As far as I can see there's no need to use `givens=...` at all.